# Laravel 6.0 How to use Route:resource get route same folder controller

Tags: laravel

I have question and I'm can't find a solution in document

I use command

```
php aritsan make:controller Backend\ProductController --resource --Model=Model\Product
```

So, I will need route same location file controller

I use

```
Route::resource('/backend/product','Backend\ProductController');
```

after, run a command

```
php artisan route:list
```

and this result
[image]

But, I don't need this
I think should be

```
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                              | Name            | Action                                                     | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | backend/product                  | backend.product.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController@index       | web        |
|        | POST      | backend/product                  | backend.product.store   | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController@store       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | backend/product/create           | backend.product.create  | App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController@create      | web        |
```

Route name should be `backend.product.index`

I find a solution. but not happy.

```
Route::resource('/backend/user','Backend\UserController')->names([
    'index' => 'backend.user.index',
    'store' => 'backend.user.store',
    'edit' => 'backend.user.edit',
    'update' => 'backend.user.update',
    'destroy' => 'backend.user.destroy',
]);
```

[Documents resource names](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes)

Comment: You should have a **/backend/product** route with the name `backend.product.index`. Try running `php artisan route:list --path=backend/product`

Comment: it shows route in the path. but not change route names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command for creating **Model Controller with resource**

```
php artisan make:controller Backend\ProductController --resource --Model=Model\Product
```

Change **web.php** and use `prefix`, `namespace`, `as`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'backend','namespace'=>'Backend','as'=>'backend.'], function () {
    Route::resource('product','ProductController');
});
```

Now use

```
php artisan route:list
```

> backend.product.index

> backend.product.create

> backend.product.show

> backend.product.destroy

> backend.product.update

> backend.product.edit

Comment: In essence, the difference is that this answer sets a prefix name `backend.` that is attached to the name of each routes in the rout group.

Comment: Yes, it will attach `backend.` in every route which exists in that group. It'll attach namespace `Backend` as well.

Answer (score 0):

refer Routing page in Laravel Documents for more details.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-prefixes